# Query Selector not working on template literals

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a script that renders some HTML content and looks like this.

```
renderJobs = async () => {
const jobs = await getJobs();
const view = `
    ${jobs.map(companyName => `
        <div class="show">
            <div class="company-details">
                <p>${companyName.company}</p>
                <object type="image/svg+xml" data="${companyName.logo}"></object>
                <h3>${companyName.position}</h3>
                <p class="details">${companyName.postedAt} - ${companyName.contract} - ${companyName.location}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tags">
                <p>${companyName.role}</p>
                ${companyName.languages.map(lang => `
                    <p>${lang}</p>
                `).join('')}
                <p>${companyName.tools}</p>
                <p>${companyName.level}</p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    `).join('')}
`
return view }
```

Now, I'm trying to select all of the children on every div with the class tags. So I can later loop through them and render only the cards that have certain content.

Here is the snippet for that:

```
selector = () => {
const tagName = document.querySelectorAll('.tags').children;
console.log(tagName)}
```

But it returns undefined, I am not aware if using template literals the rules change for the DOM. I tried the event listener DOMContentLoaded but did not seem to work.
I also tried the length property to see id there was anything coming back, but all I got was 0.
Thank you

Comment: because an html collection does not have children. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a list of html elements. So it doesn't have any `children` property. You will have to loop over all the elements are then get the children. If you want all element's children when you can use `flatMap()`

```
const tagName = [...document.querySelectorAll('.tags')].flatMap(x => x.children);
```

Comment: It makes sense, I just don't understand why after the flatMap method it returns an empty array. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: @ChristianPerez It shouldn't return empty array. Please make a snippet to show the problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vrnkeLsy/ Thanks for your time.